# How to 'split' a tkinter Frame with two different objects on each side

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Thanks in advance for your time. I am writing a chess program using the tkinter module. I have put the board interface on the left side of the screen, while on the right side I would like to have the algebraic notation (e.g. 1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6) printed and updating as the players make their moves.

Since the text is updating, I tried to create a Label widget and a StringVar() object. But it is having some trouble : Basically, there is no right side to the screen, and the with each move the window flickers violently before showing the move in algebraic notation in the center of the right side of the window. Then, for each move, the same spasm occurs, the window expands a tiny bit, and eventually the string runs off the screen.

Ideally, every two moves, there would be a new line, but for now I would be content to just have the text 'wrap' once it hits the end of the frame.

I tried to create a Canvas widget and use the create_text() method to do it, but it was a bit unwieldy (though that seems to have been the best so far).

```py
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

class Chessboard(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.pack()

        self.master.title('Chess')

        self.mainframe = tk.Frame(master, width = 1600, height = 800)
        self.mainframe.pack(side = 'top', anchor = 'n')


        self.move_data = {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'piece': None, 'to': None, 'from': None, 'last': None, 'color':'w', 'enem_color':'b'}
        self.draw_board(master)

        self.counter=2
        self.en_passant = []

        self.pgn_frame = tk.Canvas(self.mainframe, width = 500, height = 640, bd = 5, relief='ridge', cursor = 'trek')
        self.pgn_frame.pack(side='right')

        self.pgn_txt = ''
        self.pgn_str = tk.StringVar()
        self.pgn_label = tk.Label(self.pgn_frame, textvariable = self.pgn_str)
        self.pgn_label.pack(fill='both', expand = True)

    def draw_board(self, master):

        self.board = tk.Canvas(self.mainframe, width = 680, height = 680, borderwidth = 20)
        self.board.pack(fill='both', expand=True, side='left')
        for r in range(7, -1, -1):
            for c in range(8):
                if c&1 ^ r&1:
                    fill = 'sienna2'
                else:
                    fill = 'wheat1'
                x0, y0 = c*80+24, r*80+24 
                x1, y1 = c*80+104, r*80+104
                coords = (x0, y0, x1, y1)
                center = ((x0+x1)/2, (y0+y1)/2)
                sq = files[c] + ranks[-r-1]
                self.board.create_rectangle(coords, fill=fill, width = 0, tags = ('square', sq))

Chessboard().mainloop()
```

I will note that the draw_board() function creates a canvas within the self.mainframe Frame and places it to the 'left'. Again, thank you for your time !

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The code you posted isn't enough to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I have updated the code to make it a somewhat workable example, though to include the entire code that would allow for pieces and their movement would be a bit too long. I hope that, at the very least, the chess board is visible, and the rest will require a little bit of imagination !

Answer (score 0):

After searching the annals of SO, I stumbled across an ancient piece of wisdom from this question's first commenter :

"tkinter widgets are designed to shrink (or expand) to exactly fit their children." -[Label within a Frame (Tkinter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761155/label-within-a-frame-tkinter)

This little tidbit has put me on the right track to solving my problem : previously, I was trying to pack a Label widget into a Frame or Canvas widget, with the logic that the child should adapt to fit its parent. But, thanks to Mr. Oakley's insight, I have simplified the code to evict the superfluous widget and simply design my Label widget to meet the needs of the program. So, reformatted, it looks like

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

class Chessboard(tk.Frame):

   def __init__(self):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self)
       self.pack()

       self.master.title('Chess')

       self.mainframe = tk.Frame(master, width = 1600, height = 800)
       self.mainframe.pack(side = 'top', anchor = 'n')


       self.move_data = {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'piece': None, 'to': None, 'from': None, 'last': None, 'color':'w', 'enem_color':'b'}
       self.draw_board(master)

       self.counter=2
       self.en_passant = []

       self.pgn_txt = ''
       self.pgn_str = tk.StringVar()
       self.pgn_frame = tk.Label(self.mainframe, width = 500, height = 640, bd = 5, relief='ridge', cursor = 'trek', textvariable = self.pgn_str)
       self.pgn_frame.pack(side='right')

   def draw_board(self, master):

       self.board = tk.Canvas(self.mainframe, width = 680, height = 680, borderwidth = 20)
       self.board.pack(fill='both', expand=True, side='left')
       for r in range(7, -1, -1):
           for c in range(8):
               if c&1 ^ r&1:
                   fill = 'sienna2'
               else:
                   fill = 'wheat1'
               x0, y0 = c*80+24, r*80+24 
               x1, y1 = c*80+104, r*80+104
               coords = (x0, y0, x1, y1)
               center = ((x0+x1)/2, (y0+y1)/2)
               self.board.create_rectangle(coords, fill=fill, width = 0, tags = ('square'))

Chessboard().mainloop()
```

It ain't pretty at the moment, but soon, it will be. In the actual program, the text updates without the aforementioned spasms, though will need to work a little on the formatting.